# Getting an "unauthorized_client" when tryging to get a new access token, why?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman

I'm developing an API using VS 2017, which I'm testing using Postman. I've been following this blog post [Getting started with Windows Azure AD Authentication using Postman](https://medium.com/agilix/getting-started-with-windows-azure-ad-authentication-using-postman-e37a185b642d). I finally got it to give me an access token and a refresh token. About 3 quarters of the way through the post I came across this:

resource : https://management.core.windows.net

which has to be put into Postman (I'm using the Windows app version of Postman). I wasn't sure what that was for, so I left it off. I eventually got an access token and a refresh token, but when I when to get more info for all subscriptions, I got errors saying that I had specified a valid resource. So, I thought what I'd have to do was start over again, but re-authenticating and getting a code from Azure. I did so, and put that into Postman, as the blog post instructs. However, issuing this POST results in this error:

```
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: d37abf69-42ce-4571-b146-f3422e73f041. Resource value from request: https://management.core.windows.net. Resource app ID: 797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013. List of valid resources from app registration: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.\r\nTrace ID: 9f028899-6d03-409e-8db4-4e9905000300\r\nCorrelation ID: ec253a1b-9fdc-495f-9310-6b40a42e5d93\r\nTimestamp: 2018-11-19 22:20:02Z",
"error_codes": [
70002,
65005
]
```

I don't understand why nor what I could have done wrong. I've prespecified the resource as the tutorial instructed, so what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, it seems you could have missed adding relevant permissions for "Windows Azure Service Management API" to your app registration.

Steps:

1. Go to Azure Portal > Azure AD > App registrations > Your app (with app id: d37abf69-42ce-4571-b146-f3422e73f041)
2. Go to Settings > Required permissions > Add > Select "Windows Azure Service Management API"

   [image]
3. Select the relevant permission under Delegated permissions section. Click on select and then "Done". You should get a notification in portal that successfully added permissions. You should see Windows Azure Service Management API listed under required permissions as well.

   [image]

After these steps, continue as per the blog post you've mentioned with Postman steps to get the access token again.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation when i was trying to setup Postman. Its not as complicated as most blogs make seem.  I created a tutorial to try to make the process easy.

http://hazelnest.com/blog/blog/2018/11/17/azure-postman-configuration/

https://youtu.be/2bfgeBKRxl4

Hope this helps.